# ORACLE Trigger on INSERT and UPDATE for table containing the trigger condition

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

I have a configuration table with records used to control a process in my application. Normally I would have the table controlled by the application, but for now it's not possible (no money, no time etc.). So, for now the table would be managed by a client like SQL Developer or so. To ensure thet the table is filled properly I need a trigger, because check constraints don't work with custom functions. Trigger on INSERT works just fine, but I have trouble with the trigger on UPDATE, because all the conditions for the trigger to check are in the table itself an I get an error from ORACLE, that the table is being updated at the moment, so the trigger can't be fired.

Table consists of the following columns:

```
ID, SOURCE_SYSTEM, TARGET_SYSTEM, TABLE_ID, VALID_FROM, VALID_THROUGH
 1,             2,             3,      455, 01.12.2011.    02.11.2013
```

The condition is the following:

- can't have a new record with the same SOURCE_SYSTEM, TARGET_SYSTEM and TABLE_ID and an DATES that overlap with the existing ones  - NEW.VALID_FROM and NEW.VALID_THROUGH must be outside the existing period. For the example - both must be < 01.12.2011 or > 02.11.2013.

So my question is, is there a way to make this work on UPDATE too? I've read about using a materialized view for the trigger, but I think I might have problem with the data between the table and the view not being in sync.

Thanks for the help!
al

ps. Using Oracle Release 12.1.0.2.0

UPDATE: Here's the on INSERT trigger:

```
create or replace 
trigger SINGLE_QUELLSYSTEM_INSERT
BEFORE INSERT ON CTL_WEBADMIN_ABGLEICH FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE 
    v_count_rows NUMBER;
BEGIN
  dbms_output.ENABLE (buffer_size => NULL);
  dbms_output.put_line('Start...');

  IF(:NEW.CLDB_QUELLSYSTEM_ID = :NEW.CLDB_ZIELSYSTEM_ID) THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20336, 'Quellsystem ist gleich dem Zielsystem. Bitte, korrigieren Sie Ihre Abfrage.');
  END IF;

  IF(:NEW.GUELTIG_BIS < :NEW.GUELTIG_VON) THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20338, 'Datum BIS liegt vor Datum VON. Bitte, korrigieren Sie Ihre Abfrage.');
  END IF;     

  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO v_count_rows FROM CTL_WEBADMIN_ABGLEICH;
  dbms_output.put_line('Anzahl der Zeilen in der Tabelle CTL_WEBADMIN_ABGLEICH: ' || v_count_rows);
  IF (v_count_rows >=1 ) THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('Mehrere Zeilen in der Tabelle CTL_WEBADMIN_ABGLEICH vorhanden. Checking trigger condition...');
    -- FOR r in (SELECT DISTINCT CLDB_QUELLSYSTEM_ID,CLDB_WEBADMIN_TABLE_ID, GUELTIG_BIS, GUELTIG_VON FROM CTL_WEBADMIN_ABGLEICH where GUELTIG_VON >= sysdate )
    FOR r in (SELECT DISTINCT CLDB_QUELLSYSTEM_ID,CLDB_WEBADMIN_TABLE_ID, GUELTIG_BIS, GUELTIG_VON FROM CTL_WEBADMIN_ABGLEICH)
    LOOP
      IF ((r.CLDB_QUELLSYSTEM_ID != :NEW.CLDB_QUELLSYSTEM_ID OR r.CLDB_QUELLSYSTEM_ID = :NEW.CLDB_QUELLSYSTEM_ID) and r.CLDB_WEBADMIN_TABLE_ID = :NEW.CLDB_WEBADMIN_TABLE_ID ) THEN
      dbms_output.put_line('Ein anderes Quellsystem wurde für das System: ' || r.CLDB_QUELLSYSTEM_ID || ' schon spezifiziert. Checking Gültigkeit...');
        IF (r.GUELTIG_BIS is null OR (:NEW.GUELTIG_BIS >= r.GUELTIG_VON AND :NEW.GUELTIG_BIS <= r.GUELTIG_BIS) OR 
            (:NEW.GUELTIG_VON >= r.GUELTIG_VON AND :NEW.GUELTIG_VON <= r.GUELTIG_BIS) OR 
            (:NEW.GUELTIG_VON <= r.GUELTIG_VON AND :NEW.GUELTIG_BIS >= r.GUELTIG_BIS)) THEN
            RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20337, 'Gültigkeitsbereiche mit schon existierenden Einträgen kollidieren!');
        END IF;
      END IF;
    END LOOP;
  END IF;
END;
```

The on UPDATE trigger is the same, except for the declaration part, which is

```
create or replace 
trigger SINGLE_QUELLSYSTEM_UPDATE
BEFORE UPDATE ON CTL_WEBADMIN_ABGLEICH FOR EACH ROW ...
```

And the error I'm getting:

```
ORA-04091: table CLDBDEF.CTL_WEBADMIN_ABGLEICH is mutating, trigger/function may not see it
```

Comment: It will help if you post your trigger, along with how you tried to make it work for update.

Comment: Please show your code!

Comment: If you want to query across rows in a trigger, you'd need to do so in a statement level trigger not a row level trigger.  Depending on how large this table might be, you may simply want to validate every row every time the trigger fires (though that's less efficient than it could be).  A more efficient solution would be to store the key(s) in a packaged collection in a row-level trigger and just process the collection in the statement level trigger.  But that's more work.

Comment: I'm too lazy to make this into an answer.  But here are a couple of sample implementations, one trigger based and one based on materialized views  A couple of example implementations http://jeffkemponoracle.com/2012/08/30/non-overlapping-dates-constraint/  Since you're on 12.1, I'd expect that you could do something easier using the new temporal validity functionality but I'd need to verify that.

Comment: Thank you for the link! I didn't know about those compound triggers. The example looks a lot like mine. I'll try it and let you know.

Comment: @JustinCave The compound trigger worked for me, thank you. Could you please make this an answer, so that I can accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> ORA-04091: table CLDBDEF.CTL_WEBADMIN_ABGLEICH is mutating,
>   trigger/function may not see it

[Mutating Error](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e17126/triggers.htm#g1699708) occurs when a statement causes a trigger to fire and that trigger references the table that caused the trigger.

**How to avoid it :**

1. Don't use Triggers
2. Use an "after" or "instead of" trigger
3. Re-work the trigger syntax
4. Use autonomous transactions

**Reference: -**

[Fix Oracle Mutating error](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_avoiding_mutating_table_error.htm)